# A property of sum of independent binomial random variables

Tags: probability, binomial-distribution

Define independent random variables $$X = B(n_1,p), Y = B(n_2,p), Z = B(n_1+n_2+1,p).$$ Given that $$Pr[X \geq a] > c, Pr[Y \geq b] > c,$$ where a and b are positive integers, and c is a constant in (0,1), can we show that $$Pr[Z \geq a+b] > c?$$ I've tried using convolution, but the resulting expression is too hard to simplify and produce the desired result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is no. If $n_1=n_2=2, p=\frac 12, a=b=2, c=0.24$ then

$$
\Pr(X\geqslant a)=\Pr(Y\geqslant b)=\frac 1 4>c.
$$

But
$$
\Pr(Z\geqslant a+b)=\frac{6}{32} <c.
$$

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help! Just curious, if we restrict b = 1 would be the answer be different? (the question was inspired by a research question in which we know explicitly b = 1)

Comment: Then you need to show if $\Pr (Z \ge a+1) \ge \Pr(X \ge a)$. I feel it may depend on $p$. Why don't you try $p$ close to 0, and to 1, and vary $a$ on a computer and see what happens?

Comment: Just checked :) you're right. Thanks again!